# Why does Bootstrap 4 card images use data-src and not src for image tags?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

In the demo code below it uses data-src but no img src. How is the image applied? Does the javascript modify this somehow?

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

```
 <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yep, its loaded with javascript to allow lazy loading of images

Comment: Thanks @jpschroeder. But I could see cards used in ecommerce or portfolio applications. If it relies on javascript won't this negatively impact image SEO? Will google make the connection between the image and the alt text? I guess speed trumps image organic search.

Comment: Google's search bots won't download your image anyway, so from an SEO perspective, just make sure your alt text is accurate (unless you really need it to show up in google image search). The most important thing is going to be speed. Of course, there is nothing preventing you from assigning your own `src=''` attribute directly though if you're uncomfortable relying on javascript (not a bad position to take imo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 documentation uses holder.js, see http://imsky.github.io/holder/

Also see: https://github.com/imsky/holder#usage

> Include holder.js in your HTML:
>
> Holder will then process all images with a specific src attribute,
>   like this one:
>
> The above tag will render as a placeholder 300 pixels wide and 200
>   pixels tall.
>
> To avoid console 404 errors, you can use data-src instead of src.

Holder is included via http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js

Comment: Thank you for your help and answer!